# Ignite 2.14.0 Exception with Date column (java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Failed to marshal object with optimized marshaller) JDK 17

Tags: ignite, java-17

Running Sample Code Ignite standalone application Exception been thrown while on Insert and Select query statment. Code snippet is given below.

**Exception**

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Failed to marshal object with optimized marshaller: 2023-02-06
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection$StreamState.readResponses(JdbcThinConnection.java:1580)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Here is below attached the query for reference...  Solution expecting is Date field storage

**Maven Depenedency**

```
<properties>
        <ignite.version>2.14.0</ignite.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.COLL_6_2_23_4 (
    PRIMARY_ID INTEGER,
    COLLECTION_ID VARCHAR(20),
    CLIENT_ID VARCHAR(20),
    TRADE_DATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_ID PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
);
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder;
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test objTest = new Test();
        objTest.execute();
    }
public void execute() throws SQLException {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setClientMode(true);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        String[] serverIp = "127.0.0.1:48510".split(";");
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(serverIp));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1,10801/");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        try {
            try (Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(
                        "select * from PUBLIC.COLL_6_2_23_2");
                System.out.println(rs.next());
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IgniteSQLException(
                         e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            conn.close();
        }
        ignite.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it works with TIMESTAMP instead of DATE?

Comment: Yes it works.. But we do have existing data in PRD DB...

Comment: Issue has been resolved with Date field as this require to add --add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED in application and even in Ignite jvmDefaults.sh.. We need to inform ignite team change the doc and jvmDefaults.sh https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/setup